# Support QtCore library path in PyInstaller

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside, pyinstaller

I just found a way to support all image formats in QtCore like below

```
from PySide imnport QtCore...

QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(QtCore.__file__), "plugins"))
```

However, when I build the application with `PyInstaller` under Windows I still having issue with suporting JPEGs/BPMs... looks like this path was not been added to compiled application.

How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on simple ideas from http://qt-project.org/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_Windows

I added to my `app.spec` file following code:

```
from PySide import QtCore

plugins=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(QtCore.__file__), "plugins\\imageformats")
static_files += Tree(plugins, 'plugins\\imageformats')
```

and to `app.py`(main form):

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(QtCore.__file__), "plugins"))
```

Everything is working!

Comment: If this solved the problem for you, you can mark this answer as the solution so others can see that this question has been answered successfully.